# Isolated voltage measurement with an ACS37800

Tags: voltage-measurement, isolation, leakage-current

I am measuring 250VAC with an [ACS37800.](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs37800-datasheet.ashx?sc_lang=en&hash=1C7B0351F268B7F35F9A980074E4AA61) It happens to be a PWM based output of a TRIAC. For testing purposes, I am varying the duty cycle and input voltage to validate the measurement circuitry. My circuitry is very similar to the circuitry in the datasheet (first page of datasheet.)

As I vary the duty cycle of my TRIAC (one second period,) the expected output voltage is input voltage * sqrt(duty_cycle). I am measuring that output voltage. I have an isolation transformer (a 1:1 style,), and a two pole variac (schematic below.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLC8ib.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I run the autotransformers with an output of 120V, everything looks as expected. When I run the isolation transformer, there is an offset for 0 output (like 80volts,) and the voltage at full on is much lower. The weird part is when connected without any transformer, my measured values are actually inverted (as if I am measuring the voltage across the TRIAC, but I am not.) Instead of voltage vs duty cycle looking like f(x) = 300x, it looks like f(x) = 300(1-x). I do know that the external circuitry which essentially connects earth ground to the DC ground plays a role. I am trying to simulate this effect in LTspice and have not been successful.

How can this be simulated in LTspice? My assumptions of a resistance between earth ground and digital ground so far only results in f(x) = x*c, where the constant c changes.

Here is a representative schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnjk9k.png)</sup>

[image: voltage vs duty cycle for isolation transformer]
[image: voltage vs duty cycle for no transformer]

Comment: 1st) Triac can't be driven with PWM signal. 2nd) It is not clear where do you put those transformers, post a schematics. 3rd) This device is supposed to measure voltage without any transformer.  4th) Upload some scope traces, schematics for better understanding.

Comment: I added a better overall schematic. The pwm is through an optoisolator, it is definitely possible.

Comment: The device is not galvanically isolated from measured source, so you have to use isolation if you want to connect it to PC with mains directly connected.

Comment: "*It happens to be a PWM based output of a TRIAC. ... As I vary the duty cycle of my TRIAC (one second period,) ...*" We don't call what you're doing "PWM". Your period is too slow and the output isn't a pulse - it's multiple AC mains cycles and all of them complete cycles as you have mentioned in the comments below that it's a zero-cross opto-isolator (but the schematic doesn't show that). "Time-proportional control" would be a better term. The technique is commonly used in industrial heating controllers. Your naming this as PWM is what has caused confusion in your readers.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. I split the 4.2k resistor in half, grounding the junction between them instead of one end.

Answer (score 0):

It called phase angle control, not PWM.

[Source of the image:](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-calculate-rms-voltage-from-triac-phase-angle.572668/)

[image]

And of course it is not linear as you say

> f(x) = x*c,

rather a trigonometric/square function:

$$V_{load_{RMS}} = Vpeak *\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi - 2 \varphi + sin2 \varphi}{4\pi}}$$

EDIT:

The IC is for energy metering, so it has to be connected on 50/60 Hz voltage, not a load voltage. The current measures the load current, then you get a power/energy value.

Comment: I am not using phase angle control. It is a zero crossing optotriac.